# Is it possible to make a conditional OR Scan with DynamoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am currently making queries to DynamoDB using Ruby on Rails (the `HashModel` object), and I need to be able to make an OR request.

My current usage looks like this (which works great):

```
@requests = Request.dynamo_db_table.items.where(approved: 'true').and(group: params[:g]).select.map(&:attributes).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @user_settings.default_page_size)
```

But I need to be able to do something like this:

```
@requests = Request.dynamo_db_table.items.where(approved: 'true').and(group: params[:g]).or(secondary_group: params[:g]).select.map(&:attributes).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @user_settings.default_page_size)
```

`or()` is not a method on the `HashModel` object though, so it dies, but I can't figure out if there's another way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Condition expression and see if it helps- [AWS Blog](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1MFYEN4VA16U6/Amazon-DynamoDB-Document-API-in-Ruby-Part-2-Condition-Expressions)